# 2 tabels query and spend a value

Tags: mysql

2 tabbells query and spend a value the subid a lead and sale table
I would like to have read the subid
if there is something with the condition

```
select l.,s.usubid 
from leadkamp as l,salekamp as s 
WHERE l.lastupdate>='2019-06-01 00:00:01' and 
      l.lastupdate<='2019-06-27 23:59:59' and 
      s.lastupdate>='2019-06-01 00:00:01' and 
      s.lastupdate<='2019-06-27 23:59:59' and 
      l.`user` = '2' and s.`user` = '2';
```

Comment: So.... whats the question...?

Comment: Good query bro, and the question?

Comment: Please use modern `JOIN` syntax, available since SQL-92.

Comment: Fehler: #1064 - Errors in the SQL syntax. Please look up the correct syntax in the manual at 's.usubid

Comment: ```
select usubid 
from leadkamp UNION select usubid 
from salekamp 
WHERE lastupdate>='2019-06-01 00:00:01' and 
      lastupdate<='2019-06-27 23:59:59' and 
      `user` = '2';
```